# Notification about deleted comments

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Today (or yesterday) a comment I gave as a reply to a comment on one of my answers got deleted. I not only have an idea on why, but would have never noticed, had not someone else commented the answer too.

So, is there a way to get notifications about deleted comments (and ideally a reason why they were deleted too)?

Comment: Meh, I get the "that's annoying" part of it, but I'm not sure we'd need all the subsequent "My comment was special!!" whine that would result in.

Comment: @Bart: For me it  is, that I want to understand. Maybe also to improve. When you can't think for a reason of what was possibly wrong with it. Of course, every comment is special ;)

Comment: Hey, you're free to ask when you notice. But when we start notifying users for every deleted comment (which aren't meant to be permanent to begin with) I can foresee a lot of "Not constructive? Why?" "Why is this obsolete?" "Why is that rude or offensive when the OP's mother really is a ...".

Comment: @Bart: Hm, I see where you are coming from. But I am mostly hesitant to ask, because in the time the moderators answer my question, they probably could do much more useful stuff. Would these maybe get better with higher rep? At 10k you get access to moderator tools, so maybe part of them could be to see your own deleted comments?

Comment: Given how de-emphasized comments are in general, I'd say it's unlikely to be implemented. But hey, what do I know. :)

Comment: @Bart: In 230 reps, much more? ^^

Comment: For the record, mods, when you do this, it really pisses me off. And not in a way that you want.

Comment: So today a comment I made in answer to a comment on one of my answers to a question got noticed by Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/jmnr07/that_is_a_good_excuse/) and then someone decided to remove my comment, presumably because lots of people up-modded my orignal answer from 21 (to 90 last time I checked). 

I would have liked to have been notified of when and why my comment was removed.