# Can we specify which on-site notifications we get, and when they get displayed?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

For example, events such as,

- New comments,
- New answers,
- New privileges,
- Reputation changes,
- An edit to one of your posts,
- [And whatever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258179/2246344) [new notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252859/2246344) [that get introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252055/2246344) [at a later date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256352/2246344).

Could each have their own notification settings, such as ,

- *Always* notify me,
- Notify me if I'm not on the same page that the event occurred,
- Do *not* display notifications from a particular post.
- Only notify me if there's more than `X` notifications to be displayed (or, if I've earned more than `X` rep),
- Only display notifications every `X` minutes/hours,
- *Never* notify me.

<sup>(These are only suggestions, I don't expect *all* of these options to be implemented.)</sup>

As currently we are notified for *every single event* that occurs, even if we're on the same page that the event happened; so it would be nice to have at least some form of basic control over which notifications get displayed, and how often.

Comment: These settings should be split over the various types of notifications. I'd like to be able to set 'Only display notifications every x mins' to control how often the 'New questions/answers activity' banner (and glowing favicon) appears when I'm not actively looking at stuff in any particular site.

Comment: @RobH Good idea; post updated.

Comment: +1 for "Never notify me". +100 if I could. Seriously, where is my super-upvote?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're blocked from asking questions on Meta.SE, so the system won't let me migrate this there. Nothing I can do about that.

Comment: @BradLarson Blocked? How come?

Comment: @Sam - I'm guessing the severe number of downvotes on some of your older proposals triggered a question-asking ban there. I'm not a moderator on that site anymore, but you could ask the community team to maybe dissociate one or two of those from your account.

Comment: @BradLarson Oh right, yeah I've just checked; thankfully it's only a Q ban. Ok, I'll give them a bell.

Comment: Never notify me could probably be done on an individual basis by writing a few adblock rules to block the notifications.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Don't show me notifications or comments from sites I'm logged out of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157405), [Is there a way to disable all forms of notification for a specific site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179434), [Filter inbox notifications for the current site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126478)

Answer (score 3):

The "never notify me" option can already be achieved simply by hiding the notification symbols.  Here are a few user CSS rules to do it:

**Hide the green *+n* rep notification icon:**

```css
.topbar .icon-achievements .unread-count {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This style leaves the achievements icon subtly shaded green when you have new achievements, the way it normally appears e.g. when your only new achievement is a badge.  To hide that effect too, add in the following style:

**Hide the green shading for the achievements icon:**

```css
.topbar .icon-achievements.icon-achievements-unread {
    background-position: -220px -54px !important;
}
```

(The `background-position` is copied from the normal style for the achievements icon; it might change if the CSS sprite used for the icons is ever modified.  A more robust, but also more complicated, solution would be to override the achievements icon background entirely to use a custom image.)

For completeness, the inbox and flag notification icons can also be hidden:

**Hide the red inbox notification icon:**

```css
.topbar .icon-inbox .unread-count { display: none !important; }
```

**Hide the brown flag notification icon:**

```css
.topbar .icon-flag .unread-count { display: none !important; }
```

Of course, these CSS tricks only implement a tiny part of this feature request, but, based on the comments above, they might still be useful for some people.