# Why is the Community user having another battle with the moderators?

Tags: discussion, migration, community-user

I recently posted [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261022/2246344) a few days ago and haven't edited it for over two days, so I was surprised to see it at the top of the Active posts tab again, especially seeing that a moderator had modified the post without actually changing the text/tags. So I went to investigate the revision history...

> [image]

At first sight, admittedly it looked quite comical, but after further thought this raised a few questions... Why was the post closed in the first place? Why did Community keep unlocking and instantly locking the post? Why did the moderators keep closing and reopening the post?

<sup>I know I've see a post similar to this somewhere (I can't find it at the moment), but I don't think Community kept instantly locking and unlocking the post in that one though.</sup>

Comment: Skynet. Need I say more?

Comment: I suspect your post was being *migrated*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters A Mod tried to migrate it, but couldn't. Would that have caused all this?

Comment: Exactly, and the migration failure causes the close/unlock/lock notice/reopen sequence.

Comment: @Cerbrus today, it's messing around with posts. Tomorrow, it's messing around with our killer flying drones. This is how it begins. Better get those fallout shelters ready...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh right. So the Mod had to close the post to migrate it, couldn't so Community locks/unlocks the post?

Comment: Sam, the mod gave a reason for the failure to migrate...

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah I know about that. I didn't know migrating it would have caused Community to lock/unlock it like that though.

Comment: Apparently, it does :P

Comment: @Cerbrus So do you know *why* it has to lock/unlock it?

Comment: Does this mean Shog is really [Kyle Reese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_Reese), sent back in time from the near apocalyptic future to stop the Community User Machine Uprising?

Comment: @Cupcake +1 for the Terminator references :)

Comment: @sam I'd guess it's the SE version of `synchronized`

Comment: @Cupcake [Private Qarlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soldier_%28The_Outer_Limits%29#Copyright_issues) grumble Soldier - Ellison grumble.

Comment: You're all correct. This is the beginning, if you're not wearing 20 million sunblock, you're gonna have a real bad day get it?

Comment: Still waiting for Community to post something, hopefully on a site where I have rep to downvote.

Comment: Holycrap, 35 votes on my skynet comment o.O

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As Brad Larson tells you [on the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261022/can-we-specify-which-on-site-notifications-we-get-and-when-they-get-displayed#comment46261_261022):

> Unfortunately, you're blocked from asking questions on Meta.SE, so the system won't let me migrate this there. Nothing I can do about that.

Both he and Shog9<sup>*</sup> tried to migrate your post, but it was *automatically bounced back*. Normally a migrated post is locked in 'migrated away' mode, but because the migration fails, you see an immediate *unlock* being entered.

Because it all is automated and happens instantly, the Community User *Lock* and *Unlock* messages appear reversed in the edit history.

This is what *normally* happens when a post is migrated away, then *later on* rejected (because the post was closed on the other end):

[image]

What is missing in yours is the *Post Migrated Away* and *Migration Rejected* notices. There is no point, the migration failed.

<sup>* <sub>I guess Shog9 missed that Brad already had tried to do so</sub></sup>.

Comment: The sort order should probably be on `datetime, id` instead of `datetime` alone. This would disambiguate the order of rows with the same timestamp.

Comment: It would also be nice if the migration code ran a preliminary "does it look like this could be migrated?" check *before* messing with the post history in any way. Yes, there would presumably need to be a second check due to race conditions, but that should rarely fail.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Still, that would probably invite bugs: Code that is not exercised is likely broken. Good examples: Multi-codepoint characters in Unicode, multi-codeunit codepoints in UTF-16.