# How/Why were my comments deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I downvoted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311347/pthread-equivalent-to-c11) question, commenting that googling would have given the answer.

While I was slightly curt, I don't think my comment was flagged and the user isn't a moderator. So according to 
[this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment) he shouldn't have been able to delete my comments.

I'm curious as to how/why my comments were deleted.

Comment: I "like" the confidence in the phrase "I don't think my comment was flagged." As if such flagging was obvious.

Comment: Well, I was completely clueless about the LMGIFY rule. My bad.

Comment: I think getting notifications for comment deletions would be cool. There's already been a [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252859/notification-about-deleted-comments?rq=1) about it, but I would never have realized my mistake had I not posted this here.

Comment: *"I don't think my comment was flagged"*

What do you base that belief on, when **all evidence** points to the contrary? 

Of course your comment was flagged.

Comment: I have noticed that, since maybe the first of May, many of my comments are being deleted.  Admittedly, some of them are of the LMGTFY nature (which I feel is a legit comment, when you're trying to "guide" a user to do their own work) but a number were pretty innocuous.  Has something changed, or has some moderator simply gotten a bug up their posterior and gone to checking what I write?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments that Googling would have found the answer are considered rude and unhelpful (see previous discussions [LMGTFY link can't be added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added) and [Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) for example), so it's entirely possible that the comment was flagged and removed as a result.

Comment: So how should I respond to an easily googleable question?

Comment: Be lighthearted and joyful! "I found a couple of things during a Google search that might help you out. Look at these: http://www.google.com etc." While still DV'ing the question.

Comment: You can post an answer (citing sources if applicable). If it's a duplicate of another question on SO, vote to close as such if you have that privilege - if not, comment with the duplicate link.

Comment: @nishantjr - "Google is your friend" (the comment that was removed, twice) is pretty rude, don't you think? In any case, Stack Overflow is often the destination for Google searches, so this can end up being a cyclical reference.

Comment: @Brad, Yes, I realize that now. I did not think

Comment: I didn't see the comment, so I don't know if the context made it rude, but I've heard "Google is your friend" without it being rude.  It doesn't seem any worse than things like "Ask the rubber duck".  Sometimes it's a useful way to explain to a user *how* they should search on Google.  E.g., "A Google search for `site:stackoverflow.com "error: unexpected frob"` turned up some duplicates."  This way they learn to use site:stackoverflow.com **and** get in the habit of searching for exact error messages.

Comment: @Josh Big difference between a comment that says, simply, "Google is your friend", and a comment that gives *constructive advice* on search terms that can be used to find an answer. Guess which one I would flag?

Comment: @CodyGray - Why flag either?  There are a lot of folks asking questions that can easily be answered with Google, or by consulting readily available documentation or whatever.  If these people are not "instructed" they will keep on adding noise to SO, subverting it's supposed "mission" to develop an "archive" of information.